# How does vortioxetine cause nausea when it inhibits 5HT3-receptors?

Tags: antidepressants, nausea, ssri-selective-serotonin

5HT3  Inhibitors are antiemetics, such as Mirtazapine. See [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16632163/) and [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=R0dvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=vortioxetine+nausea+mechanism&source=bl&ots=CZmmgAcEJW&sig=ACfU3U08cOKguMMExrg3rftawbH_Ebuqxg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1n6GI7sXqAhXYgVwKHZgsBGgQ6AEwHHoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=vortioxetine%20nausea%20mechanism&f=false)

The serotonin modulator vortioxetine is such an inhibitor, and the most common side effect is nausea, in [3](https://www.lundbeck.com/upload/ca/en/files/pdf/pm/TRINTELLIX_Product_Monograph_English.pdf) it says that it has a 5HT3-inhibitor effect.

I am confused. Can someone explain the contradiction between explanations?

Comment: In what monograph?

Comment: Product monograph is the paper about the medicine distributed by the manufacturer

Comment: I'm not sure the above answers the original question, or my question below! I have a patient who was prescribed vortioxetine. He then complained of nausea and was prescribed mirtazapine. However the nausea persists. A common side-effect of a course of treatment of vortioxetine appears to be nausea (and perhaps again with discontinuation!) but this is odd if it is a 5HT-3 inhibitor - unless its GI operation is somewhat independent.

Answer (score 2):

Its primary action is as NaSSA (a noradrenergic and specific serotonergic antidepressant), not as 5-HT3 inhibitor. If you have a look at e. g. the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirtazapine#Pharmacodynamics), you will see that nausea is listed as side effect under "discontinuation syndrome", i. e. sudden withdrawal from continuous 5-HT3 blocking.
As a side note, it also has H1-blocking effects, which are antiemetic as well.

There are more withdrawal symptoms listed here: https://www.nami.org/About-Mental-Illness/Treatments/Mental-Health-Medications/Types-of-Medication/Mirtazapine-(Remeron)

Comment: Thanks but if you read more, you can see that it's used as an antiemetic for chemotherapy side effects because of its 3ht3a antagonist property

Comment: Read more where?

Comment: See edit of the question

Answer (score 1):

I was mistaken, the 5HT3 inhibitor of Vortioxetine is not responsible for the nausea, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=vortioxetine+nausea)

> Its additional antagonism of 5-HT3 receptors may partly counteract gastrointestinal adverse effects but nausea has an important role on drug discontinuation.

His 5HTI agonist property contributes to Nausea.

Its additional antagonism of 5-HT3 receptors may partly counteract gastrointestinal adverse effects but nausea has an important role on drug discontinuation.

Comment: It may be that my answer said just that.

Comment: If it's the case I will remove immediately my answer but please make it clearer